# LINQ: Select nodes that doesn't have a parent

Tags: linq

I have a simple tree structure represented like this:

```
Node
{
   int Id;
   int ParentId;
   int Name;
}
```

Using LINQ with a List<Node>, how can I select all nodes that doesn't have a parent in the same list?

Example:

```
Id  ParentId
1   0
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   4
8   6
```

In the above table, Nodes with Id 1 and 8 doesn't have a parent in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res = nodes.Except(from node in nodes
                       join pnode in nodes
                         on node.ParentId equals pnode.Id
                     select node);
```

or:

```
var res = from node in nodes
          join pnode in nodes
          on node.ParentId equals pnode.Id into jnodes
          from jnode in jnodes.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where jnode == null
          select node;
```

or:

```
var res = nodes.Where(np => !nodes.Any(n => np.ParentId == n.Id));
```

Comment: This is a solution that is very easy to read, something I value. Just out of curiosity, this O(n) right?

Comment: Honestly, I can't estimate that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
var parents = new HashSet<int>(nodes.Select(node => node.ParentId));
var orphans = nodes.Where(node => !parents.Contains(node.Id));
```

You *could* just use:

```
var orphans = nodes.Where(node => !nodes.Select(x => x.ParentId)
                                        .Contains(node.Id));
```

but that would be an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation, whereas the first version is O(n) assuming normal hashing efficiency. Obviously if n is small it won't matter much...

Comment: Why did you use `HashSet` here?

Comment: @Pr0fess0rX: To make the overall operation O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: What LINQ books is your favorites? Does your C# book cover all of LINQ?

Comment: @Carl: My book is *mostly* about the language side - it doesn't go into EF etc. I don't really have a favourite LINQ book, to be honest. I've rarely needed anything beyond LINQ to Objects, and that's self-taught...

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = from n in list
            where list.Count(p => n.ParentId == p.Id) == 0
            select n;
```

Comment: This looks very much like the previous dataset solution I'm updating. Great to know that the same kind of expression can be used in LINQ. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = list.Select(i => i.Id).ToList();
var result = list.Where(i => !ids.Contains(i.ParentId)).Select(i => i);
```

EDIT: added `.ToList()` to insure that Contains work
EDIT2: reversed the operation to answer the question right.

Comment: Wasn't quite sure `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` has this extension method. My mistake :)

Comment: @jon-skeet i think `ToList()` us useful if he is using EF so he would not go each time to collect the ids, or what do u think? I think here it does the same purpose of `HashSet` or not?

Comment: @Pr0fess0rX: The OP describes using `List<Node>` to start with. In an EF situation I'd *definitely* avoid the `ToList` call - that way EF can do the relevant join *within SQL* rather than pulling all of the parent IDs down to start with and then sending them back up.

Comment: @jon-skeet ok, but you see now no need for `ToList()` in any case, right?

Comment: @Pr0fess0rX: `ToList` would be useful if the original collection was expensive to iterate over, but didn't implement `IQueryable` - or if we were trying to join it with a local data source, for example.